# Python3 bottle SQLite3 Quiz - update with variable colum name and datalist

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, bottle

I am making a little web quiz using bottle. The web part functions well, I can display the questions and POST the answers back to my main.py. As I loop through the POST data, I append the tupple (Qn, ans) to a datalist[].

var no being the first question number on each page, I create this list this way :

```
        datalist=[]
        datum=()

        for i in range(no,nend):
            noQ = "Q"+str(i)
            rep = request.POST.get(noQ)
            rep= int(rep)
            #print (f"{noQ}: {rep}")
            datum=(noQ,rep)
            datalist.append(datum)
```

This is the format for the first page:

> ('Q1', 4) ('Q2', 3) ('Q3', 6)

The second page's datalist looks like this:

> ('Q4', 4) ('Q5', 3) ('Q6', 4) 
>   and so on

I need to add the answers to the table in the database. 
Since I display the quiz 3 questions per page, I want to batch update the table 3 answers at a time. The column names thus increment Q1, Q2...Qn. 
It looks so simple, but when I put together the statement:

```
cur.executemany("UPDATE Q_R SET ?=? where id = 1", datalist)
```

(ID will change too), I get :

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

I tried to use some string formatting in there, but it just laughs at me.

cur.executemany("UPDATE Q_R SET %s?=? where id = 1", datalist)

I know it's for updating multiple columns, so somehow I should have something resembling:

```
cur.executemany('UPDATE Q_R SET %s=?, %s=?, %s=? where id=id', what goes here ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to make 2 tuple lists during the loop, then append the ID at the end of the rep_list. So the code is like this:

```
statement="UPDATE Q_R SET %s=?, %s=?, %s=? where id=?" % tuple(Q_list)
cur.execute(statement, rep_list)
```

Sometimes, explaining the problem is solving it. Thanks for the help.